# Extra space in a element horizontally scrolled element with relatively positioned items

Tags: html, css

Scrolling items inside a small wrapping element is something relatively easy to do, but in my case, the items inside this overflowed container are relatively positioned so each one of them overlaps the previous.

It's still easy, I just needed to manipulate the `left` of each element:

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width: 400px;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align:top;
  white-space:normal;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.item:nth-child(1) { left: 0;       z-index: 1;  }
.item:nth-child(2) { left: -30px;   z-index: 2;  }
.item:nth-child(3) { left: -60px;   z-index: 3;  }
.item:nth-child(4) { left: -90px;   z-index: 4;  }
.item:nth-child(5) { left: -120px;  z-index: 5;  }
.item:nth-child(6) { left: -150px;  z-index: 6;  }
.item:nth-child(7) { left: -180px;  z-index: 7;  }
.item:nth-child(8) { left: -210px;  z-index: 8;  }
.item:nth-child(9) { left: -240px;  z-index: 9;  }
.item:nth-child(10) { left: -270px; z-index: 10; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I couldn't get rid of this extra space to the right that appeared right after stacking the items on top of each other.

I can't shrink the parent — `.container` — so I tried, as you can see, shrink an inner element without success.

How could I "trim" this space?

Comment: Remove `position:relative;` from `.item` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your inner div with `overflow: hidden`, the total width of the stacked items will not exceed the width of the inner div.

You need to set inner width to something like 670px.

Comment: Actually, the total width of the elements was too much. But the total of `left` used plus any `padding` (omitted here) did the trick. Thak you for tour time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `position:relative;` from `.item` class

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width: 400px;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  /*position: relative;*/ /*Remove this*/
  vertical-align:top;
  white-space:normal;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.item:nth-child(1) { left: 0;       z-index: 1;  }
.item:nth-child(2) { left: -30px;   z-index: 2;  }
.item:nth-child(3) { left: -60px;   z-index: 3;  }
.item:nth-child(4) { left: -90px;   z-index: 4;  }
.item:nth-child(5) { left: -120px;  z-index: 5;  }
.item:nth-child(6) { left: -150px;  z-index: 6;  }
.item:nth-child(7) { left: -180px;  z-index: 7;  }
.item:nth-child(8) { left: -210px;  z-index: 8;  }
.item:nth-child(9) { left: -240px;  z-index: 9;  }
.item:nth-child(10) { left: -270px; z-index: 10; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't because, otherwise, I can't stack them on top of each other.